# Read the lines in various txt files outputting these lines in a single line and a single file

Tags: batch-file

I'm very basic to bat and need help doing a script that joins the lines of several txt files on a single line and a single file.
for example:
these are the files:

***W7BR71754L.txt***

```
Relatório de Hardware:
Nome:W7BR71754L
S.O.:Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 
Usuário:GMEA\SESA197328
Serial:5CB2204XTP
```

***W7BR71760L.txt***

```
Relatório de Hardware:
Nome:W7BR71760L
S.O.:Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 
Usuário:GMEA\SESA97408
Serial:5CB2190BPX
```

***newfile.txt***

```
Relatório de Hardware:;Nome:W7BR71754L;S.O.:Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ;Usuário:GMEA\SESA197328;Serial:5CB2204XTP;
Relatório de Hardware:;Nome:W7BR71760L;S.O.:Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ;Usuário:GMEA\SESA97408;Serial:5CB2190BPX;
```

This is something I'm working on, but its not doing exactly what i need...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "text="
for /r %%G in (*.txt) do (call :sub "%%G")
:sub
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
 set "text=!text!%%a"
)
>>newFile.txt echo !text!;
```

Comment: never mind guys, got it to work:

Comment: @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r %%G in (*.txt) do (call :sub %%G)

:sub
set "text="
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
 set "text=!text!%%a;"
)
>>newFile.txt echo !text!

Comment: @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r %%G in (*.txt) do (call :sub %%G)

:sub
set "text="
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
 set "text=!text!%%a;"
)
>>newFile.txt echo !text!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, it's just getting the new line into the file that you need to add.

This will concatenate all the files text into one file - each file's contents separated by a line.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set text=
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (%%a) do (
set text=!text!%%x
)
echo !text! >>newfile.txt
set text=
)
```